# I want and you want, but a higher power wants

Tags: idiom-requests

'I want and you want, but a God/higher power wants'

This is an Arabic idiom used when 2 people don't get what they want and they believe a higher power got what he wants, and it is maybe for the better.

Comment: What is the question? Do you want an equivalent idiom that is familiar to English speakers?

Comment: Yes, that is my question.

Comment: You may use this quite similar expression: "God's ways are not our ways".

Comment: *One potato, two potato* comes to mind. Dunno why...

Answer (score 2):

From *De Imitatione Christi* (*The Imitation of Christ*) by Thomas à Kempis, in the original Latin:

> *Homo proponit, sed Deus disponit.*

the translation of which gives us the saying

> Man proposes, but God disposes.

In other words, human beings may declare the outcomes they desire, but God decides what happens.

Comment: I proposed to myself that I would give this answer first. But God disposed it and handed it over to one @deadrat! :P